# I need to install openvpn 2.4, how would i go about this?

Tags: openvpn

i need a newer version of openvpn installed since i need the support for ncp-ciphers. How would be the correct way of installing a newer version of openvpn that is not in the repo?

Answer (score 2):

There is a wiki on the OpenVPN website that is quite good and will walk you through the steps. You should be able to follow the instructions as though you are installing for Ubuntu 16.04 which elementary 0.4.1 is based upon.

Here is the link:

https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenvpnSoftwareRepos

Good Luck!!!